# Variance of inverse RV

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, moment-generating-function

I am trying to find variance of Y=`1/(1+abs(x))` where X is Gaussian RV with mean m, var sigma^2To do that my initial step is to find MGF. can anyone give me suggestions on how to find it?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. This seems to be a homework or assignment problem. So, a minimal effort or approach to the problem is appreciated. Is the transformation bijective? If so, can you find the distribution? If not, then what? Stating if the efforts will be helpful to answer your query.

Comment: Hi, I was able to find the CDF of the given y which is nothing but derivative of difference of two CDFS. which i used to find the Expectation. E[y]= integrate(1-CDF). But now i am looking to see how the system behaves wrt to variance. !/(1+abs(x) is throwing me off and any help would be appreciated